# Select the rows (A:J) if column E contains more than 4 Cells with value. Next selective print the selected Rows. repeat process till last value

Tags: excel, vba

Select the rows (A:J) if column E contains more than 4 Cells with value. Next is to selective print the selected Rows. Then it need to repeat the process until the last filled cell. Have been searching for a macro to get tenter link description herehis done for weeks but sadly to no avail.
Hope you all can assist me on this.

[After being select as such i believe i could just proceed with printing under "printing selection" setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avOti.jpg)

[This is one of the printed result of the 2 selected row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DH1Fl.jpg)

> Added code from comments

```
Sub EnquiryPrep() 
Dim x As Integer 
Dim rng As Range 
With ActiveSheet 
   LR = .Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 
   For Each cell In .Range("e7:e" & LR) 
      If cell.Value <> "" Then 
          If rng Is Nothing Then 
            Set rng = cell.Offset(, -4).Resize(, 10) 
          Else 
            Set rng = Union(rng, cell.Offset(, -4).Resize(, 10)) 
          End If 
       End If 
    Next cell 

   rng.Select 
End With 
End Sub
```

Comment: Show an example of what it would look like afterwards

Comment: hi dbmitch, im very new to posting question in stackoverflow. do you happen to know of how to get it done using vba/excel macro?

Comment: Get what done? Show what it would look like with sample data - and after macro runs

Comment: hi dbmictch, im really sorry but how do i attached sample data.

Comment: so sorry as i am really new to this site in uploading questions. however i have attached an image as example of highlighted rows that i expect it to turn out. which then i just need to print and change the setting to "print selection"

Comment: it'll need VBA code to run in a loop. Does every user get separated by one blank row?

Comment: hi dbmitch, yes every user will be seperated by one blank row.

Comment: hi dbmitch, below is the by far closest vba i got. but it doesnt filter more than 4cells with value and also it leaves gap for the blank cells which causes issue with print selection.

Comment: Sub SELECTING()
Dim LR As Long, cell As Range, rng As Range
With ActiveSheet
    LR = .Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For Each cell In .Range("A7:J" & LR)
        If cell.Value <> "" Then
            If rng Is Nothing Then
                Set rng = cell
            Else
                Set rng = Union(rng, cell)
            End If
        End If
    Next cell
    rng.Select
End With
End Sub

Comment: Added some code you can test. To get proper formatting of print headers and page titles, it's best to record your own macro and insert it at the end of the sub. Make sure to show your testing code in your edited post (at top) and wrap with code tags

Comment: hi dbmitch. i manage to get a better vba code. but still its lacking to filter only those rows that contain more than 4 cells with value. below codes only select all rows range .i think im almost there..

Comment: Sub EnquiryPrep()
Dim x As Integer
Dim rng As Range
With ActiveSheet
LR = .Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For Each cell In .Range("e7:e" & LR)
    If cell.Value <> "" Then
        If rng Is Nothing Then
            Set rng = cell.Offset(, -4).Resize(, 10)
        Else
            Set rng = Union(rng, cell.Offset(, -4).Resize(, 10))
        End If
    End If
    Next cell
rng.Select
End With
End Sub

Comment: Have you tried my answer code?

Comment: hi dbmitch, i have tried your answer. it gave our error code 1004, debugged and highlighted at the code "   Selection.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False"    i delected the code and try to run it but nothing happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this into your ThisWorkbook Code

> WHAT IS OUTPUT FROM DEBUG.PRINT statments?? Cut/Paste from Immediate
>   window below code

Try:

```
Sub PrintValidRows()

    Const SHEET_NUM     As Integer = 1 ' Which Sheet to Use

    Const CHECK_COL     As Integer = 5 ' Column E
    Const START_ROW     As Integer = 8
    Const MIN_FILLED    As Integer = 5 ' Min number required for print

    Const LAST_COL      As String = "H" ' Last column to print

    Dim lastCellBlank   As Boolean
    Dim lngRow          As Long

    Dim lngLastRow      As Long
    Dim lngStartRow     As Long
    Dim intNumFilled    As Integer

    Dim strRange        As String
    Dim strPrintRange   As String

    Dim ws              As Worksheet

    Set ws = Sheets(SHEET_NUM)
    ws.Activate
    ws.Cells(1, 1).Select

    intNumFilled = 0

    ' Get last row of data
    lngLastRow = ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row

Debug.Print "Last Row: "; lngLastRow

    lngStartRow = START_ROW

    For lngRow = START_ROW To lngLastRow

        If IsEmpty(Cells(lngRow, CHECK_COL)) Then

            If intNumFilled >= MIN_FILLED Then
                strRange = "A" & lngStartRow & ":" & LAST_COL & lngRow - 1

Debug.Print "Adding Range: " & strRange

                If lngStartRow = START_ROW Then ' first range
                    strPrintRange = strRange
                Else
                    strPrintRange = strPrintRange & "," & strRange
                End If
            End If

            ' Reset Filled Cell Counter
            intNumFilled = 0

            ' Reset StartRow to next row
            lngStartRow = lngRow + 1
        Else
            intNumFilled = intNumFilled + 1
        End If


    Next lngRow

    ' Check for last set of data
    If intNumFilled >= MIN_FILLED Then

        strRange = "A" & lngStartRow & ":" & LAST_COL & lngRow - 1
Debug.Print "Adding Range: " & strRange

        If lngStartRow = START_ROW Then ' first range
            strPrintRange = strRange
        Else
            strPrintRange = strPrintRange & "," & strRange
        End If
    End If

' Show Print Range in Immediate Window
Debug.Print "Print Range: " & strPrintRange

    If strPrintRange <> "" Then
        Range(strPrintRange).Select
    End If

    ' You can record a macro to get it to printout exactly what how want
    ' REMOVE THIS TO TEST HIGHLIGHTING
    'Application.Selection.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: hi dbmitch, thank you but theres a run time error "1004" and it highlighted at the "Selection.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False"

Comment: i deleted the code that gave out error.i tried to run the code but nothing happened.

Comment: Recopy/paste code - I added a debug to print the Range it calculated. If you've changed the spreadsheet layout start row and check column - make sure to change constants at top - and Update your image in your post

Comment: hi dbmitch, i checked and use the current code it still pops up  run-time error 1004. debug. still highlight the same code.

Comment: What did the debug statement say - delete the print statement for now - that's nothign that I can test at all to match your system

Comment: i tried again. it highlight " Range(strPrintRange).Select"      its at the  If strPrintRange <> "" Then
            Range(strPrintRange).Select
        End If

        ' You can record a macro to get it to printout exactly what how want
        Selection.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False

Comment: run-time error "1004": Method "Range" of object"_Global" failed

Comment: STOP! ....Read what I asked. WHAT DID THE DEBUG.PRINT say in the Immediate window???

Comment: i have deleted the debug codefor print that you place till the print code that causes error. I run the code but nothing happened.

Comment: run-time error "1004": Method "Range" of object"_Global" failed    so i click debug and it highlighted "Range(strprintrange).select"

Comment: hi dbmitch, i tried again your code. this time no error. but it only select cell A1.

Comment: This is my last response if I don't get a proper reply indicating you're doing what I've asked. Using <Ctrl>-G from the code window will show you the Immediate window - copy/paste those results into here. copy/paste screen image of your code window into your question box above.

Comment: hi dbmitch, im really sorry to cause you to be angry over my stupidity. but honestly i recopied your code now. rerun the macro. ther is no error now. however it only select cell A1. thats all.

Comment: hi dbmitch, im grateful for your assistance.. really appreciate it. i will try to look out for other sources and ask around  . Thank you buddy.

Comment: Answer these 3 questions: What is your a) worksheet name - AND b) is it the first worksheet? What is the first row of your data - is it still row 8? Is column E still used to monitor data?

Comment: Worksheet name: Breakdown Report - 9 JUNE. First worksheet name: hawb. First row of my data is row 8. Yes column E is used to monitor data.

Comment: What is the location number for the Breakdown Report worksheet in the workbook tabs? - Put that number in the first row "Const SHEET_NUM     As Integer ="

Comment: hi dbmitch, i manage to google out the error for 1004. the correct code is Selection.PrintOut Copies:=1     . this miraculosly can print without error.